# Поиск минимальных пиков

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня имеется массив чисел[image: введите сюда описание изображения],
мне нужно найти пиковые минимальные значения, которые будут отделять перепады. Я сглаживаю график фильтром Савола и ищу минимумы с помощью argrelextrema(data, np.less), но получаю и лишние точки, которые явно видно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Может кто подсказать, как можно найти данные значения?

Comment: посмотрите [этот вопрос и ответы](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571260/scipy-signal-find-peaks-cwt-not-finding-the-peaks-accurately) в английской версии SO

Answer (score 0):

задай delta скажем 100
и удали каждую точку для которой есть в пределах +-delta другая точка с меньшим значением.